# MySQL not deleting a row on Ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

My delete button:

```
$('#taglist li #delete').bind('click', function(){
        pic_id = $(this).parent().attr("rel");
        $.post('savetag.php', {"type":"remove", pic_id:pic_id}, function(data){
            viewtag();
          });
    });
```

savetag.php

```
if ($_POST['type'] == "remove")
{
    $pic_id = $_POST['pic_id'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM image_tag WHERE `pic_id` = $pic_id";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Here is the script that views the tags, viewtag.php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM image_tag ORDER BY `pic_id`";
$qry = mysql_query($sql);
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($qry);

if ($rs){
  do{
    echo '<li rel="'.$rs['pic_id'].'"><a>'.$rs['name'].'</a> <a class = "delete">Delete</a></li>';
  }while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($qry));
}
```

Here is the function that allows viewtag.php into my index.php:

```
viewtag();

    function viewtag()
    {
     $.post('viewtag.php', function(data){
            $('#taglist ol').html(data);
          });
    }
```

So what is the problem, why is it not deleting the table? Also the anchor tag isn't working (anchor tag which is echoed from viewtag.php). What is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: are you getting ajax response? just `echo "hi";` before `$pic_id ` in your `savetag.php` and checkout.

Comment: echo $pic_id in your savetag.php file and check that its display ID or not ?

Comment: Open the dev tool bar or Firebug (if using Firefox) and begin to look at the Ajax request (did it contain all parameters ?). Secondly, add a PHP echo in your savetag.php to check the SQL request. In other words..debug. You can also give us your HTML code, it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i could see is .. your `<a>` tag isn't working since the tag is added dynamically so you need to use `on` delegate event..and notice your `<a>` has a class but your selector is  id.. use `.delete` as a selector

```
$('#taglist').on('click','a.delete', function(){  //u can use #taglist li a.delete too
    pic_id = $(this).parent().attr("rel");
    $.post('savetag.php', {"type":"remove", pic_id:pic_id}, function(data){
        viewtag();
      });
});
```

you can go through the [link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/) if you want to read more about on event

Comment: welocme... happy coding.. let me know if any problem ... :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you're selecting for ID, but you have a class:

$('#taglist li #delete').

should be:

```
$('.delete').bind('click', function(e){
        pic_id = $(this).parent('li').attr("rel");
        $.post('savetag.php', {"type":"remove", pic_id:pic_id}, function(data){
            viewtag();
          });
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

Your links won't work because they have no href tag, so how do the browser knows the right anchor?

```
  <?php while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($qry)): ?>
     <li rel="<?php echo $rs['pic_id'];?>"><a href="#<?php echo $rs['name'];?>"><?php echo $rs['name'];?></a> <a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></li>
  <?php endwhile;?>
```

Also, I suspect there are issues in he viewtag() function too, but you didn't post the relative html so I can't help much on that